# how to return multiple id after insert rows before flush in doctrine zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, frameworks

I am inserting multiple rows and i want to retrive all rows id in same time in doctrine zend framework 3.

```php
        foreach($rippleids as $rid)
        {
            $scheduleItem=[];
            $scheduleId=[];
            $rippleid = StaticFilter::execute($rid, 'StringTrim');
            if (empty($rippleid)) {
            continue; 
            }

                //return;
        $schedule= new Schedule();

        $id= uniqid();
        $schedule->setScheduleUId($id);
        $ripple=$this->entityManager->getRepository(Ripple::class)->findOneBy(['id'=>$rippleid,'status'=>[1,2]]);
        $schedule->setRipple($ripple);
        $template=$this->entityManager->getRepository(Template::class)->findOneBy(['Id'=>$data[2]]);
        $schedule->setTemplate($template);
        $schedule->setStatus(1);
        $schedule->setScheduleName($data[1]);
        $schedule->setRecordingEnable($data[5]);
        $schedule->setStartDateTime($startDateTime);
        $schedule->setEndDateTime(  $endDateTime);
        $schedule->setScheduleStatus(0);
        $schedule->setModifiedDate(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
        $schedule->setSyncStatus(0);
        $this->entityManager->persist($schedule);
$this->entityManager->persist($schedule);
        $scheduleId=$schedule->getScheduleId();
```

this code return only one Id but i want retrive all rows inserted id

Answer (score 0):

this is a simples question, you need add [] on $scheduleId.

Looks like this:
$scheduleId[]=$schedule->getScheduleId();